# Python BeautifulSoup - Find all elements whose class names begin with some string

Tags: python, html, string, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

Assume that we want to find all `li` elements whose class names all begin with a known string and end with an arbitrary id number.

That means that this approach doesn't work:

```
soup.find_all("li", {"class": KNOWN_STRING})
```

I have also tried this approach without any luck:

```
soup.select("li[class^="+KNOWN_STRING)
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: in this approach `soup.select("li[class^="+KNOWN_STRING)` you may have forgot to close the brackets. Try `soup.select("li[class^="+KNOWN_STRING+"]")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use [regex](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) in this approach.

```
import re

soup.find_all('li', {'class': re.compile(r'regex_pattern')})
```

Because you have a known string but an arbitrary (I'm assuming unknown) number you can use a regular expression to define the pattern of what you expect the string to be. Example:

```
re.compile(r'^KNOWN_STRING[0-9]+$')
```

This would find all known strings with one or more numbers at the end. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html) for more about regular expressions in Python.

## Edit, to answer the question:

> Would this be correct given two digits in the id? soup.find_all('li', {'class': re.compile(r'^TheMatch v-1 c-[0-9][0-9]+$')}). I assume that it wouldn't.

For two digits at the end you would do:

```
soup.find_all('li', {'class': re.compile(r'^TheMatch v-1 c-[0-9]{2}$')})
```

The `+` just means one or more of the previous regular expression.

What I did was specify in brackets `{2}` after the regular expression the number of instances I was expecting to be there `2`.

Comment: Would this be correct given two digits in the id? soup.find_all('li', {'class': re.compile(r'^TheMatch v-1 c-[0-9][0-9]+$')}). I assume that it wouldn't.

Comment: @user3257755 I made an edit to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You select is incorrect, just use KNOWN_STRING, don't wrap it it quotes and make sure you use a closing bracket:

```
soup.select("li[class^=KNOWN_STRING]")
```